# Add days to current date

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

Am new to clojure, can anyone help me to understand how can I get current date in clojure and then adding days to it?
for e.g. adding 3 days to current date?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idiomatic Clojure way is to use [clj-time](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time) (see link for Leiningen/Maven install instructions), which wraps Joda time as referenced by the first answer from [overthink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69689/overthink).

```
user=> (use '[clj-time.core])
nil
user=> (now)
#<DateTime 2014-11-25T12:03:34.714Z>
user=> (plus (now) (days 3))
#<DateTime 2014-11-28T12:05:40.888Z>
```

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a Clojure-specific answer, really, but I'd use [Joda time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

```
(import 'org.joda.time.DateTime)
(let [now (DateTime/now) 
      later (.plusDays now 3)] 
  [now later])

;; [#<DateTime 2014-11-24T23:26:05.885-05:00> #<DateTime 2014-11-27T23:26:05.885-05:00>]
```

Comment: You could make it Clojure-specific by pointing at the `clj-time` wrapper around Joda time. :)

Comment: @xsc Fair enough. Looks like someone else provided such an answer.

Comment: Does this answer /really/ require a downvote?  Could the downvoter please explain?

Answer (score 1):

```
user> (import '[java.util Calendar])
;=> java.util.Calendar
user> (defn days-later [n]
        (let [today (Calendar/getInstance)]
          (doto today
            (.add Calendar/DATE n)
            .toString)))
#'user/days-later
user> (println "Tomorrow: " (days-later 1))
;=> Tomorrow:  #inst "2014-11-26T15:36:31.901+09:00"
;=> nil
user> (println "7 Days from now: " (days-later 7))
;=> 7 Days from now:  #inst "2014-12-02T15:36:44.785+09:00"
;=> nil
```